# correlation between 25 variables in r

Tags: r

I have a regional dataset and I have to analyze it in the R language. I have to provide the recommendations where can an organization promotes their programs. I want to find a correlation between 25 attributes. can anybody help me out with this?

Comment: You can check the `cor`

Answer (score 1):

We can just use `cor` to get the correlation between the columns

```
out <- cor(df1)
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(25), 5, 5))
```

Comment: I have 24 numeric attributes and 1 attribute is character, so how i deal with it?

Comment: @RonakPatel  Just subset the numeric columns and apply the `cor` `i1 <- sapply(df1, is.numeric); cor(df1[i1])`